# azurerm_virtual_machine (remote-exec): (output suppressed due to sensitive value in config) Terraform output

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm looking for a way to see what is going on during creation of a virtual machine since I use complex cluster configuration and to test if its working I need to be able to see the output and in some cases I'm not due to sensitive. This is related to running remote-exec option

**module.MongoInstall.azurerm_virtual_machine.MongoVirtualMachine[2] (remote-exec): (output suppressed due to sensitive value in config)**

could you please help me

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
inline = [
  "chmod +x /tmp/mongo-activate.sh",
  "cd /tmp",
  "sudo ./mongo-activate.sh ${var.username} ${var.vmpassword} ${var.mongopassword} ${local.isCluster} ${join("," ,azurerm_public_ip.MongoPublicIpAddress.*.fqdn)} ${var.hasArbiter}",
  "rm mongo-activate.sh",
]

connection {
  type     = "ssh"
  host     = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.MongoPublicIpAddress.*.ip_address, 0)}"
  user     = "${var.username}"
  password = var.vmpassword
  timeout  = "15m"
}
```

}

Example of variables:

```
     variable "vmpassword" {
    default = "testtesttest"   //psw:mongo VM
}
```

Comment: What is the TF code producing the message?

Comment: Updated the description of the question

Comment: Can you use `cloud-init` instead of `remote-exec`? The logs would be on the instance.

Comment: This is by design: When a provider configuration includes a sensitive value (from a sensitive variable, output, or resource attribute), Terraform will suppress logging from the provisioner. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/26611

The workaround is to use the function nonsensitive() around the variable you are passing to bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You [Adnriy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14944568/andriy-bilous) for your suggestion.

Yes we can not see the sesitive value in console like password and Key after terraform apply .Terraform will suppress logging from the provisioner.If provisioner configuration or connection info includes sensitive values, we need to unmark them before calling the provisioner. Failing to do so causes serialization to error.

Like you can see in below image
[image]